# REST Client for .net core 2

Tags: restsharp, rest-client, asp.net-core-2.0

Are there any REST(Http) Client libraries available for .net core 2 like RestSharp..?
I have been using RestSharp but it doesn't support .net core 2 so looking for one.
Please let me know if you have any suggestions... Thanks in advance..

Comment: You're much better off just using `HttpClient` directly; using something like RestSharp doesn't buy you much.

Comment: The only problem with HttpClient by itself is that there a few things that it doesn't do for you like serialization and deserialization for strong typing. If you're going to use HttpClient, you at least need to put a layer over the top that converts your objects to json strings and back. That's the simple aim of RestClient.Net

Comment: I agree with @ChrisPratt. I do not WANT any automated serialization occurring in my REST API calls because it obfuscates specific serialization errors and any type changes or unexpected types and properties. In one particular 3rd party API I was invoking, it would return a JSON array on success but a JSON object on failure, which caused complicated de-serialization exceptions.

System.Text.JSON can be used for serialization and de-serialization in .NET Core 2.  

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-migrate-from-newtonsoft-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0

Answer (score 0):

Well, have you looked at pre-release packages?

https://www.nuget.org/packages/RestSharp/106.0.0-alpha0284

Answer (score 0):

Yep.

RestClient.Net

https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/RestClient.Net

NuGet: RestClient.Net

It's my library and you can hit me up for support on the repo. Tested heavily on Android, UWP, and .NET Core/Framework.

Answer (score 0):

I've maintained [DalSoft.RestClient](https://restclient.dalsoft.io/) since 2015 it works on .NET Standard 2.0 which means it works on full fat .NET and all .NET Core versions - including new .NET Core 2.1 features such as HttpClientFactory.

DalSoft.RestClient is simple but very extensible and flexible, it's actively maintained and battle tested by large enterprises making millions of requests every day.

https://restclient.dalsoft.io/

**This is how easy it can be, this gets all my public GitHub repos:**

```
dynamic restClient = new RestClient("https://api.github.com");

var repositories = await restClient
   .Headers(new { UserAgent = "MyClient" } // Github requires User-Agent to be set
   .users.dalsoft.repos.Get();

foreach (var repo in repositories)
{
   Console.WriteLine(repo.name);
}
```

Live example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/IT3d1E